# How do I concat a string to the end of an element of a list?

Tags: tcl

Suppose I have a list of variable length. I will just use length of 3 as an example

```
set inst_list [list a b c]
```

Now also suppose I have a variable:

```
set add_string "1"
```

I want to be able to add the $add_string variable to the last element in the list. Note that the list has a variable length and is not always 3.

The output I would want in the above example is:

```
a b c1
```

I know that if this were a fixed size list I could do something like

```
concat [lindex $inst_list 2]$add_string
```

but this would only give me "c1" not the full list with "c1" at the end. Also this does not account for variable list size of $inst_list.

Answer (score 4):

`lset` and `string cat` are appropriate here:

```
lset inst_list end [string cat [lindex $inst_list end] "1"]
```

`string cat` appears in Tcl v8.6